# How to import third party android library to java file in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am looking to import a java library to a flutter application. I understand that I will need to call the methods of this java file through a dart bridge or platform channel per https://flutter.io/platform-channels/. However I have yet to be able to make the methods from the library Im trying to import callable or importable. The methods are available when looking at the java file alone in android studio but when viewed with flutter they are unavailable.

Comment: Please add the code of what you have done so far to import the library. Also, what do you mean by "viewed with flutter"?

Comment: so far I have added 
    compile 'io.particle:cloudsdk:0.5.0' to the android gradle then made the gradle retrieve dependencies via console. just like one would import a lib to a regular android app.  by "viewed with flutter" I am referring to viewing the entire project, android ios and dart code. When you right click on the android files you can open them as an individual project like normal in android. when looking at the android files alone I can use the methods and classes in the library. when looking at the entire project It does not know the methods and classes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the extra info given, I was able to reproduce the issue.

To edit the native Android app, you have to open it in a new instance of Android Studio:

[image]

To add the the libraryx `io.particle:cloudsdk:0.5.0`, you have to add it to the `build.gradle` in the `app` subfolder. You also have to enable Java 1.8 support:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'io.particle:cloudsdk:0.5.0'
}
```

The IDE will only recognize the library when you open the Android project in a separate window. The Flutter app will still compile without a problem.

To get rid of the red error underlining in your Flutter project, you can unload, then reload the Android module (right click on `android` folder > `Load/Unload modules...`):

[image]

Comment: Actually I do not see the load/Unload modules when right clicking on the android folder. However I believe I was able to get the same desired result by clicking the "synchronize android". Regardless it compiled so thank you!

Comment: I added another screenshot that shows where the option can be found

Comment: yeah I see how the load/unload module is between the open module settings and the create gist buttons but I don't have that in my menu for some reason.

Comment: @boformer now exporting application for iOs work fine without problem? or this solution only work on android?

Comment: This whole question/answer is only related to Android and doesn't affect iOS export. Keep in mind that you cannot use Java libraries on iOS.

Comment: I did all of the points that you mentioned but still, I have red error underlining in my flutter project.